# Search index in SQL Server ignoring special characters

Tags: sql-server, search

I have an [nvarchar] column in a SQL Server table containing data like 123456789, 123-456789, 1234.56.789, 1.23456-789 and so on. The users just add dots, minus and spaces somewhere for readability and I don't know where.

Is there a way to create an index which ignores Special characters and find these when searching for plain "123456789"?

Comment: If you create a persisted computed column with your "clean" data, you could index that.

Comment: That would be an idea - but I'd prefer a collation which does this without an extra column.

Comment: Interesting: something like create custom special-characters-insensitive collation, but it seeems to me that SQL Server does not support creating custom collations.

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to use a computed column as noted above, or to create an indexed view. Doing something like creating a custom collation, even if that were possible, would simply tend to obscure the logic. Depending on the table usage (oltp vs olap) I'd use either a computed column or indexed view. The indexed view is more "obvious" to me, but... opinions vary.

Comment: VDohnal is correct in that SQL doesn't offer this sort of collation. And Katherine is correct in my opinion where an indexed view would probably be your best solution.

Comment: @Sean No need to persist it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do exactly what you want in the way that you want.

The best mechanism for doing this is to use a computed column. It does not need to be persisted to be indexed.

### Initial Position

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
  (
     YourColumn NVARCHAR(50)
  );

INSERT INTO YourTable
VALUES      ('123456789'),
            ('123-456789'),
            ('1234.56.789'),
            ('1.23456-789');
```

### Create computed column and index it.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD CanonicalForm AS 
 CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourColumn, '.', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') AS NVARCHAR(50));

CREATE INDEX ix
  ON YourTable(CanonicalForm)
  INCLUDE (YourColumn);
```

### Test it

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  CanonicalForm = '123456789'
```

### Execution plan seeks on the index

[image]